# Issues Routing React page using Apache2

Tags: reactjs, routes, apache2

I'm having issues access routes other than the home page on my React page, which is being hosted on an Apache2 web server.

This is the page: [www.TJBrackett.com](http://www.tjbrackett.com)

I've tried adding a .htaccess file to the folder containing the index.html file, but that results in a 500 error.

Apache2:

```
 ServerName tjbrackett.com
 ServerAdmin webmaster@tjbrackett.com
ServerAlias *.tjbrackett.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/tjbrackett.com
<Directory /var/www/tjbrackett.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Order allow, deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

React index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter
        basename="http://www.tjbrackett.com">
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

How I'm trying to route in the React pages:

```
<a href="http://www.tjbrackett.com/about">
```

This is my first jump into apache2 and web hosting in general. I'm not sure if I need to set up an express backend to serve the routes or if I need to setup docker for this project. Any help and tips are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed the 500 error issue. The .htaccess file wasn't being pointed to by apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by changing every "a href" to a react "link to". Also made other various changes.

New .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```

New React index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

New page links:

```
<Link to="/about"></Link>
```

EDIT: In case you're having issues with React breaking on reload in Apache, this is what I changed the Apache file to. Also the React index.js file changed a bit.

```
ServerName www.tjbrackett.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@tjbrackett.com
ServerAlias *.tjbrackett.com
DirectoryIndex index.html
DocumentRoot /var/www/tjbrackett.com

<Directory /var/www/tjbrackett.com>
order allow,deny
allow from all

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

</Directory>
```